# problema con relacion polimorfica con eloquent y laravel en dos proyectos

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polimorfismo

estoy trabajando en un proyecto (proyecto1) que inicialmente se crearon tablas y relaciones polimorficas (usuario, sessionCurso, cursos), ahora estoy en un proyecto (proyecto2) que sera una api que consulta esas tablas y relaciones

[image: valores existentes proyecto 1 de tabla polimorfica]

necesito acceder a esos valores utilizando la relacion morphMany pero esta necesita acceder a ese modelo con diferente namespace en el Proyecto2 (usuario, sessionCurso, cursos)

se puede pasar algun parametro para definir ese namespace del **proyecto1** en el **proyecto2**?

Ejemplo de lo que intento hacer:

```php
public function courseTest()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\User', CourseSessions::class, 'studentable');
}
```

este es un ejemplo de lo que quisiera hacer en el proyecto2, los modelos estan declarados en los dos proyectos pero diferentes namespaces.

Comment: si son proyectos diferentes por que necesitarias instanciar namespace que no le pertenecen ... creo que a tu proyecto 1 le hace falta un modelo de consumo de interface sea una API, para que tu proyecto 2 tenga acceso a los datos ...

Comment: es similar a cuando tiene un proyecto A (gobierno establece los contenidos de educacion), proyecto B un colegio consume el api del proyecto A para obtener los datos que necesita de las colegiaturas

Comment: antes de implementar polimorfismo, asegurate que se cumpra en paradigma de responsabilidad unica.

Comment: por ahora lo que  intentas hacer no tenemos forma de resproducirlo e incluso puede estar basado en opiniones las respuestas

Comment: otras observaciones, evita colocar codigo en imagenes, intenta presentar un error en concreto que este saliendote por pantalla y que requieras resolver.

Comment: y por ultimo la IA sugiere la siguiente implementacion: https://chat.openai.com/share/8fa212a3-ce42-4c33-92aa-d503cd80c2e6

Comment: toma esa sugerencias con pinsas no hay pruebas de su correcto funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione mapeando las relaciones por ejemplo:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

        Relation::morphMap([
            'App\Models\Lmscourse' => Course::class,
            'App\Models\LmsmoduleContent' => ModuleContent::class,
            'App\Models\LmscourseModule' => CourseModule::class,
            'App\Models\LmscourseSessions' => CourseSessions::class,
            'App\Models\LmscourseSessionTime' => CourseSessionTime::class,
            'App\Models\User' => User::class,
        ]);
```

Saludos